# Correct Preposition: the risk-adjusted cost (the cost is adjusted by, in, for, with or according to risk?)

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I cannot correctly understand the Title of academic papers such as "the risk-adjusted cost".

Here, the cost is adjusted **by**, **in**, **for**, **with** or **according to** risk?
Which preposition is more correct or comes first to the mind of a native English speaker?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *For* and *according to* both make sense. The cost is not adjusted *by* the risk -- we do that, based on the amount of risk we assign. A high-risk item of low cost is adjusted upward according to that high risk.

Comment: This is an ELL question. Consider posting on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).